# Does it meaningfully improve performance to cache everything upfront in JS

Tags: javascript, jquery, performance, caching

I have a number of elements that are reference by different blocks of JS code to do various, unrelated things. For example, something like...

```
$("#box").click(function() {
  if ($("#line").val()) {
    someFunction()
  })
})

function someFunction() {
  // some code
  $("#line").addClass("highlight")
}

function someOtherFunction() {
  type = $("#line").data("type")
  string = "type = " + type
  $("#field").empty().append(string)
}

$("#button").click(function() {
  $("#line").val("new_value")
})
```

As you can see, `$("#line")` is referenced multiple times, and manipulated or used in unrelated ways. Given that, would it be more performant to just cache `$("#line")` in a `document.ready`? So something like...

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  line = $("#line") 
})

// same code as above using cached line
$("#box").click(function() {
  if (line.val()) {
    someFunction()
  })
})

function someFunction() {
  // some code
  line.addClass("highlight")
}

function someOtherFunction() {
  type = line.data("type")
  string = "type = " + type
  $("#field").empty().append(string)
}

$("#button").click(function() {
  line.val("new_value")
})
```

In addition to performance, any other watchouts about this approach? (e.g., caching may not update values or whatever appropriately, such that `line.val()` may not change even if input actually does change, I tested this and it doesn't happen, but any other watchouts are helpful)

Comment: Don't worry about this sort of thing until later, and you have good reason to optimise. Write your most readable, understandable code first. If then you have a need, benchmark, as where you are thinking about optimising is likely never the best place to anyway (there will be other lower hanging fruit).

Comment: Yes, it would improve performance, but whether that's *meaningful* to you only you can know.

Comment: You either should wrap all your code in the ready callback, or none of it.